# Javascript - Endless recursive function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, recursion

I'm currently working on a chrome extension that let the user click on a node to get its content. Getting the inner text is simple when using `textContent`, but getting the url of a picture in a clicked `div`...

I tried using this function to get the `img` node and thus being able to read its `href`/`src`:

```
function getimgtag(elem) //elem is the clicked div
{
    for(i=0;elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];i++)
    {
        getimgtag(elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[i]);
    }
    if(elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0])
    {
        localStorage['fus_imgtag']=elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    }   

}
```

But it doesn't seems to have an end and I really don't understand why. Shouldn't it check all the `div` elements and place the last `img` found in `localStorage['fus_imgtag']`?

Comment: You forgot to declare `i` as in `var i`.

Comment: That's not the problem, but I would cache `elem.getElementsByTagName('div')` and `elem.getElementsByTagName('img')`. Calling it over and over again is a waste of resources.

Comment: @elclanrs: That's the answer :)

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll post as answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare `i` as in `var i`. If you don't declare it, it becomes an implicit global variable which is always trouble particularly in your case where `i` should be scoped locally for every recursive call.